# JavaScript only recognising first a-marker only

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, ar.js

I am trying to store the id attribute of a-marker tags and the code works fine except the JavaScript only recognises the first a-marker tag and not the second.

```
<script>
var place;
AFRAME.registerComponent('markerhandler', {
    tick: function () {
        if (document.querySelector('a-marker').object3D.visible == true) {
            el = document.querySelector('a-marker');
            console.log("gogogo");
            place = el.getAttribute('id');
            console.log(place);
        } else {
            el = null;
            place = null;
        }
    }
});
</script>

<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
<a-scene embedded arjs>

    <a-marker preset="kanji" id="2">
        <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 0.5;' markerhandler> 
    </a-box>
    </a-marker>

    <a-marker preset="hiro" id="1">
        <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 0.5;' markerhandler> 
        </a-box>
    </a-marker>

</a-scene>
```

[Codepen of the problem](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pVjLYr?editors=1111)

Included the snippet in question and a codepen to a version that works. If I switch the order of the a-markers only the first prints out in console. Just to confirm I am not showing the camera both markers at the same time.

Any pointers on this would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.querySelector()` only returns [the first matching element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

You are likely looking for [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which returns an array of matching elements you can iterate over and perform your checks on.

---

```
var markers = document.querySelectorAll('a-marker');

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i].object3D.visible == true) {
        place = markers[i].getAttribute('id');
    }
}
```

or

```
var visibleMarker = markers.filter(function(marker) {
    return marker.object3D.visible;
})[0];

if (visibleMarker) {
    place = visibleMarker.getAttribute('id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I have implemented that function and am currently printing out the id values in console. Could you possibly make a suggestion on how I might store the id for the marker I am currently looking at?

Comment: From what I can see you are doing that already by updating the `place` variable that is outside of the listener's scope - what are you aiming to achieve? If you need to store the ID for longer periods or between pages/refreshes you could look at using [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: It doesn't need to persist across pages. I just want place to be set to the ID of the marker I am currently looking at. I am just not sure how to get that array value to the place variable.

Comment: I've just added an untested edit, is that what you mean?

You basically need to iterate over all of the markers found, find the visible one and update the `place` variable with the found marker's ID value.

Comment: I'll give it a go shortly and get back to you. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

`document.querySelector('a-marker');` will select only the first one.

If you want to select all of the markers use `document.querySelectorAll('a-marker');` will do that.  And then you'll make a loop to do whatever you want to do for all those selected nodes

Something like

```
var els= document.querySelectorAll('a-marker')
for (var i = 0,  i < els.length ; i++) {
console.log(els[i].getAttribute('id');)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I just implemented something like this but am still a little stuck on how to proceed with storing the id of the marker I am currently looking at. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: what do you want with those Ids ?  you can store them in array or whatever you want NO ?

Comment: The idea is to look at a marker and store the id for the duration of looking at said marker.  Then if I look at a different marker I have access to that markers ID. I'm just a little confused on getting the ID from the array of the one i'm currently looking at. Sorry if I'm not explaining this very well but i'm very grateful for your help so far.